Scalars that are both Additive and Multiplicative inverses on secp256k1
I believe I have found two scalars (a) and (b) that are both additive and multiplicative inverses on the secp256k1 elliptic curve.
So scalars (a) and (b) meet the following criteria:
[+≡0 (mod )]
[⋅≡1 (mod )]
where n is the order of the secp256k1 curve: =0648032580364141
If you pick any point P on the curve, then using these scalers a and b the following holds true:
⋅+⋅=()
⋅⋅=
I've tried to find any references to such scalars but haven't found any. How rare are these scalars, and what are the implications, if any?

$n$ is a prime number. As its hex representation ends with 1, the multiplicative group of the field with $n$ elements (that's just additions and multiplications mod $n$) has order $n-1$, which is divisible by 4. As finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic, there is an element $x$ of multiplicative order 4, which means that $x^2$ is $-1$ modulo $n$. That's the $a$ rsp. $b$ you found. If you take some small primes to the power of $(n-1)/2$ modulo $n$, about half of them will be $n-1$. If you take such a small prime to the power of $(n-1)/4$ you get your $a$ or $b$.

@garfunkel could you convert this comment into an answer?

Thanks @garfunkel for the explanation.  How hard would it be to find the values of a  and b given the large value of n?

$n$ is a prime number. As its hex representation ends with $1$, and the multiplicative group of the field with $n$ elements (that's just additions and multiplications mod $n$) has order $n−1$, the order of the multiplicative group is divisible by $4$. As finite subgroups of the multiplicative group of a field are cyclic, there is an element $x$ of multiplicative order $4$, which means that $x^2$ is $−1$ modulo $n$. That's the $a$ rsp. $b$ you found.
If you take some small primes to the power of $\frac{n−1}2$ modulo $n$, about half of them will yield $n−1$. If you take such a small prime to the power of $\frac{n−1}4$ you get your $a$ or $b$. To my knowledge, nothing is proven about how many small primes you need to try out before finding one that gives you $a$ or $b$. (If I remember correctly, a proof of the Riemannian conjecture would show that $\mathcal O(\ln{n})$ trials should be enough, so expect not more work than such many modular exponentiations mod $n$.)

Alternatively, you can compute $r^{(n-1)/4} \bmod n$ for random values $r$; if you avoid the $r=0 \pmod n$ values, then exactly half of the random values would yield either $a$ or $b$ - hence, the expected number of random trials you'd need is $2$.

@poncho: My logarithmic term in $n$ is worst case.
